# How to add values to <option> tag loaded from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi part form to load color options based on size selection however it will not add values to the option tag and I cant seem to find the solution. What I would like is.

1. To add values to the option tags example:

   option value="X">Clear,option value="T">Smoke,option value="GS">Gunsmoke
2. Output as html the selected options text so i can display to client their selections in a readable format before they submit the final step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

My Code

```js
var Vest_10_08 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke", "Gunsmoke");
var Vest_10_10 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke", "Gunsmoke");
var Vest_10_12 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke", "Gunsmoke");
var Vest_10_14 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke");
var Vest_10_16 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke");

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Populate Select Items

    $('#SelectSize').change(function () {
        populateSelect(), populatePart();;
    });
    $('#SelectHardware').change(function () {
        populatePart();
    });
    $('#SelectColor').change(function () {
        populatePart();
    });

    function populateSelect() {
        SelectSize = $('#SelectSize').val();
        $('#SelectColor').html('');

        eval(SelectSize).forEach(function (t) {
            $('#SelectColor').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });

    }

    function populatePart() {
        SelectSize = $('#SelectSize').val();
        SelectHardware = $('#SelectHardware').val();
        SelectColor = $('#SelectColor').val();
        document.getElementById('item_name').value = (SelectSize + '66' + SelectHardware + SelectColor)

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectSize" name="SelectSize" required="">
    <option selected="selected">Select Size</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_08">10 tall X 14 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_10">14 tall X 14 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_12">16 tall X 14 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_14">16 tall X 16 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_16">18 tall X 16 wide</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id="SelectHardware" name="SelectHardware" required="">
    <option selected="selected">Select Hardware</option>
    <option value="C">Chrome</option>
    <option value="SB">Black</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id="SelectColor" name="SelectColor" required=""></select>
<br>
<br>
<input id="item_name" name="item_name" type="text" style="width: 200px" />
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Nicely formatted question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's generally considered a bad practice to use `eval` in general. A good re-write could use objects to store your values instead of using individually named variables. You can also use objects to store the value and display properties.

Something like this...

```
var vestData = {
    'Vest_10_08':[
        {
            value:'',
            text:'Select Color'
        },
        {
            value:'S',
            text:'Smoke'
        },
        {
            value:'GS',
            text:'Gun Smoke'
        }
    ],
    'Vest_10_10':[
        // ...
    ]
};
```

However, since you have duplicate items with the same values you might want one master object to reference the internal values to the display values like this.

```
var colorNames = {
    'C':'Clear',
    'S':'Smoke',
    'GS':'Gun Smoke'
}

var colorOptions = {
    'Vest_10_08':['C','S','GS'],
    'Vest_10_10':['C','S','GS'],
    'Vest_10_12':['C','S','GS'],
    'Vest_10_14':['C','S'],
    'Vest_10_16':['C','S']
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Populate Select Items

    $('#SelectSize').change(function () {
        populateSelect(), populatePart();;
    });
    $('#SelectHardware').change(function () {
        populatePart();
    });
    $('#SelectColor').change(function () {
        populatePart();
    });

    function populateSelect() {
        SelectSize = $('#SelectSize').val();
        $('#SelectColor').html('<option value="">Select Color</option>');

        colorOptions[SelectSize].forEach(function (t) {
            $('#SelectColor').append('<option value="' + t + '">' + colorNames[t] + '</option>');
        });

    }

    function populatePart() {
        SelectSize = $('#SelectSize').val();
        SelectHardware = $('#SelectHardware').val();
        SelectColor = $('#SelectColor').val();
        document.getElementById('item_name').value = (SelectSize + '66' + SelectHardware + SelectColor)

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You must change your Arrays to compute objects instead of strings. E.g:

```
var Vest_10_08 = [
  { value: '', text: "Select Color" },
  { value: 'X', text: "Clear" },
  { value: 'T', text: "Smoke" },
  { value: 'GS', text: "Gunsmoke" }
];
```

And then, when you're looping through the Array:

```
$('#SelectColor').append('<option value="' + t.value + '">' + t.text + '</option>');
```

---

Note: Nothing to do with the question, but only a tip: I don't think it's a good idea to use `eval`, the way you're doing. You could simply use a keyvaluepair object, and then you'd use the ID as its key. E.g:

```
var vests = {
  Vest_10_08: [
    { value: '', text: "Select Color" },
    { value: 'X', text: "Clear" },
    { value: 'T', text: "Smoke" },
    { value: 'GS', text: "Gunsmoke" }
  ],
  Vest_10_10: [
    /* (...) */
  ]
};
```

And then you could use it, instead of using `eval`, by doing:

```
vests[SelectSize].forEach(
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain the arrays in detail that will be very helpful later in my project. I actually used Lenny's answer for this one as both of you got rid of the `eval` in your answers.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var Vest_10_08 = new Array({name: "Select Color", option: 0}, {name: "Clear", option: "X"}, {name: "Smoke", option: "T"}, {name: "Gunsmoke", option: "GS"});

var Vest_10_10 = new Array({name: "Select Color", option: 0}, {name: "Clear", option: "X"}, {name: "Smoke", option: "T"}, {name: "Gunsmoke", option: "GS"});

var Vest_10_12 = new Array({name: "Select Color", option: 0}, {name: "Clear", option: "X"}, {name: "Smoke", option: "T"}, {name: "Gunsmoke", option: "GS"});

var Vest_10_14 = new Array({name: "Select Color", option: 0}, {name: "Clear", option: "X"}, {name: "Smoke", option: "T"});

var Vest_10_16 = new Array({name: "Select Color", option: 0}, {name: "Clear", option: "X"}, {name: "Smoke", option: "T"});


$(document).ready(function () {
        //Populate Select Items

        $('#SelectSize').change(function () {
            populateSelect();
            populatePart();
        });
        $('#SelectHardware').change(function () {
            populatePart();
        });
        $('#SelectColor').change(function () {
            populatePart();
        });

        function populateSelect() {
            SelectSize = $('#SelectSize').val();
            $('#SelectColor').html('');
            eval(SelectSize).forEach(function (t) {
                $('#SelectColor').append('<option value=' + t.option + '>' + t.name + '</option>');
            });
        }

        function populatePart() {
            SelectSize = $('#SelectSize').val();
            SelectHardware = $('#SelectHardware').val();
            SelectColor = $('#SelectColor').val();
            document.getElementById('item_name').value = (SelectSize + '66' + SelectHardware + SelectColor)

        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectSize" name="SelectSize" required="">
    <option selected="selected">Select Size</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_08">10 tall X 14 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_10">14 tall X 14 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_12">16 tall X 14 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_14">16 tall X 16 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_16">18 tall X 16 wide</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id="SelectHardware" name="SelectHardware" required="">
    <option selected="selected">Select Hardware</option>
    <option value="C">Chrome</option>
    <option value="SB">Black</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id="SelectColor" name="SelectColor" required=""></select>
<br>
<br>
<input id="item_name" name="item_name" type="text" style="width: 200px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your Colors detail inside another object. You need not to duplicate all colors value inside all "Vest_10_*"

```js
var Vest_10_08 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke", "Gunsmoke");
var Vest_10_10 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke", "Gunsmoke");
var Vest_10_12 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke", "Gunsmoke");
var Vest_10_14 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke");
var Vest_10_16 = new Array("Select Color", "Clear", "Smoke");

//New added
var Colors = {};
Colors['Select Color'] = '0';
Colors['Clear'] = 'X';
Colors['Smoke'] = 'T';
Colors['Gunsmoke'] = 'GS';

$(document).ready(function () {
 //Populate Select Items

 $('#SelectSize').change(function () {
  populateSelect(), populatePart();;
 });
 $('#SelectHardware').change(function () {
  populatePart();
 });
 $('#SelectColor').change(function () {
  populatePart();
 });

 function populateSelect() {
  SelectSize = $('#SelectSize').val();
  $('#SelectColor').html('');

  //Changes in this function
  eval(SelectSize).forEach(function (t) {
   console.log(t);
   var value = Colors[t];
   console.log(value);
   $('#SelectColor').append('<option value="'+value+'">' + t + '</option>');
  });

 }

 function populatePart() {
  SelectSize = $('#SelectSize').val();
  SelectHardware = $('#SelectHardware').val();
  SelectColor = $('#SelectColor').val();
  document.getElementById('item_name').value = (SelectSize + '66' + SelectHardware + SelectColor)

 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectSize" name="SelectSize" required="">
    <option selected="selected">Select Size</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_08">10 tall X 14 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_10">14 tall X 14 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_12">16 tall X 14 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_14">16 tall X 16 wide</option>
    <option value="Vest_10_16">18 tall X 16 wide</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id="SelectHardware" name="SelectHardware" required="">
    <option selected="selected">Select Hardware</option>
    <option value="C">Chrome</option>
    <option value="SB">Black</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<select id="SelectColor" name="SelectColor" required=""></select>
<br>
<br>
<input id="item_name" name="item_name" type="text" style="width: 200px" />
```

If you want to avoid "eval" than code is here :
http://jsfiddle.net/bhushankumar/0b4azsuf/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use a template libary like underscore or handlebars or mustache. Its bad practice to generate html from javascript.

Comment: Do you see a problem with doing this?

`        // Print Details of selected items in readable format
        SelectedSize = $('#SelectSize').find('option:selected').text();
        SelectedHardware = $('#SelectHardware').find('option:selected').text();
        SelectedColor = $('#SelectColor').find('option:selected').text();        
        document.getElementById('review').innerHTML = (SelectedSize + ' Vest with ' + SelectedHardware + ' Hardware ' + ' color is ' + SelectedColor);`

Comment: Small, simple single lines of of generated html from javascript is acceptable but dynamically populating a select box from js should be done in a template. Its much more readable.  _.template('<select><%_.each(myarray,function...)(myarray)

Answer (score 1):

You can format your input in javascript and construct and object with array inside :

```
var choices = {1:["oneValue", "twoValue"], 2:["oneHtml", "twoHtml"]};

function addInputSelect(divName) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var selectHTML = "";
  selectHTML="<select>";
  for(i = 0; i < choices.length; i = i + 1) {
  /* choices[1][i] for get the first object in array position i */
      selectHTML += "<option value='" + choices[1][i] + "'>" + choices[2][i] + "</option>";
  }
  selectHTML += "</select>";
  newDiv.innerHTML = selectHTML;
  /* append the html constructed to the dom. (divName is the html div dynamicInput) */
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newDiv);
}


<!-- html -->
<div id="dynamicInput"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addInput('dynamicInput');" />
```